# How to set xsrf token in angular for cross origin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csrf

i am using angular js in front end and laravel in back end.
I want to set xsrf token for access cross origin

but I'm getting this --> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

i have angular js module as follow

```html
angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']).run(function($http,CSRF_TOKEN){
   $http.defaults.headers.common['csrf_token'] = CSRF_TOKEN;
   });
```

and my service is as follow

```html
angular.module('myapp').factory('communitiesService', function($http) {
   return {
       get : function() {
           return $http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/communities/searchcommunities');
       }
   }
});
```

I have this in view file

```js
<script>
     angular.module("myApp").constant("CSRF_TOKEN", '<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>');
 </script>
```

can anyone provide me the complete example and explain.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

add your project uri in App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrf.php